# How to record SurfaceView preview

Tags: android, surfaceview, video-recording

I am working on an app in which I am using Surface View only for preview of frames.
Can anyone tell me how can I record videos of this SurfaceView preview?

Comment: Use the media projection APIs to record the entire screen.

Comment: I don't want to record the whole screen, I just want to record the SurfaceView preview.

Comment: AFAIK, you do not have much of a choice.

Comment: Check this 
https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 possibilities :

1 - Capture each frame of your `SurfaceView` and store all the captured bitmaps into an array, after that you can encode it to a video file using `MediaRecord`

Here's a full example of how it works : [ViewRecorder](https://github.com/z4hyoung/ViewRecorder)

2 - Using [EZFilter](https://github.com/uestccokey/EZFilter)  **(I've already tested)**, It's a little long but it's worth a try :

**XML :**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/frm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">


            <cn.ezandroid.ezfilter.core.environment.TextureFitView
                android:id="@+id/render_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <cn.ezandroid.ezfilter.view.glview.GLLinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/gl_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:visibility="invisible">

                <!--PUT YOUR SURFACEVIEW XML HERE-->
    
            </cn.ezandroid.ezfilter.view.glview.GLLinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA :**

```
GLLinearLayout mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.gl_layout);
ISupportRecord mSupportRecord;
TextureFitView renderView;
RenderPipeline mRenderPipeline = new RenderPipeline();

mRenderPipeline.setRenderSize((int) surfaceWidth, (int) surfaceHeight);
                mRenderPipeline = EZFilter.input(mLinearLayout)
                        .addFilter(null)
                        .enableRecord(videoPath, true, false)
                        .into(renderView);
                for (GLRender render : mRenderPipeline.getEndPointRenders()) {
                    if (render instanceof ISupportRecord) {
                        mSupportRecord = (ISupportRecord) render;
                    }
                }
                mSupportRecord.setRecordSize(surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
```

When you want to start recording :

```
 private void startRecording() {
        this.mSupportRecord.startRecording();
        this.mSupportRecord.enableRecordAudio(false);
 }
```

To stop recording :

```
  private void stopRecording(){
       if (mSupportRecord != null) 
            mSupportRecord.stopRecording();
  }
```

3 - You can capture the whole screen and crop the recorded video using `FFmpeg`

Comment: First approch doesnt works on SurfaceView 

https://github.com/z4hyoung/ViewRecorder/issues/1

Comment: @Rohitgupta, are you by any chance trying to record the camera SurfaceView?

Comment: @Rohitgupta if you want to record camera surfaceview try this https://gptshubham595.medium.com/unveiling-the-world-of-ar-with-arcore-my-journey-of-exploration-practical-guide-86ac7f54b34

it has a section for video recording a surface view using mediaprojection